# Looking for code for "find files containing text" in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I got several strings to search within a directory of .m files.
I would like to convert the manual operation of searching all the files containing some text (`<ctrl>+<shift>+f`) to something automatic.
I've found Yair Altman's trick to invoke that window [here](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=7FHNBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA532&lpg=PA532&dq=code%20for%20find%20files%20containing%20text%20matlab&source=bl&ots=W6UFL7Mpmp&sig=EPdwV9Q-Xj--9l1Cdub6Wzsa1l0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwifstiw4svNAhWE5xoKHROAA5Y4ChDoAQg5MAU#v=onepage&q=code%20for%20find%20files%20containing%20text%20matlab&f=false), using `com.mathworks.mde.find.FindFiles.invoke`, but this is only half way through.

Any ideas?

Comment: [`findstr`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx) for Windows, [`grep`](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) for unix

Comment: @excaza thanks, this is a good workaround.

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB has a Find Files option here:

[image: matlab.jpg]

which does exactly what you ask for.  I'm a big fan of grep, but if I'm working in MATLAB anyway, Find Files is convenient, and it's extremely fast.  It lets you search directories recursively, specify patterns of files to match (like `*.m`, or `*.txt`), and then specify a search string:

[image]

Comment: I am looking for AUTOMATION. I know this tool (ctrl+shift+f), but since I have a large number of strings, that process is too slow.

Comment: Well that's neat, I've never seen this before